# jQuery get JSON

Tags: jquery, json, post

Ok so I am able to return the JSON file fine,
But what I don't know if how get the right colum (sorry if that make no sence)

Here is the JSON output

```
[{"total":"85.91"}]
```

I want to be able to get the word total

As what plain was and is to have one $.ajax function doing all the posting back and forth to the server.

I have never done it this way but hope it can be done.

Here is my jQuery code

```
    function fetchpage(e,formstring)
{
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'system/classes/core.php',
      data: formstring,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
          $.each(data,function(i,myinfo){
            alert(data[0]);     
          });
      },
      error: function(data){
      $.each(data,function(i,myinfo){
            alert(i);       
          });
      }

    });
}
```

Comment: FYI, the error callback arguments may not be what you're expecting there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to retrieve the object keys rather than accessing each directly, eg `obj.total`.

Try the following...

```
success: function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = data[i];
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                // see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty
                console.log(key, obj[key]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I ask, why this worked? I can see that you are running two $.each commands which look at the json the first one gets the basic outline of the json i guess and then the second one allows us to look at the key and val? but why don't they just allow this from beginning?

Comment: I've replaced the `$.each()` calls with plain ole JavaScript. Might help explain the solution better

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT] See Phil's answer for double parsing (JSON + Array)

---

You can use the `.getJSON()`[<sup>**doc**</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) API that will parse your returned data:

```
$.getJSON('system/classes/core.php', function(data) {    
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    alert("my key" + key);
    alert("my val" + val);
  });
});
```

Comment: Careful, the JSON result is an array

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, myinfo) {
        alert(myinfo.total);     
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah I know I can do it this way, but as stated above I want to use this function for other POST ajax functions like getting users data etc. SO by declaring what it is I am sure i'll run into issues.

Comment: @RussellHarrower, you want to reuse the anonymous success handler for other AJAX requests? I am not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can get the word total by this way

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
alert(key)
})

this will give you word total